# Finding x for f(x) loess function

Tags: r, loess

I have a couple of loess models using similar data to....

```
set.seed(123)

y<-(runif(100,-20,20))
z<-seq(-12.75,12,.25)*rnorm(100,1,3)
x<-seq(1,100,1)
df<-data.frame(cbind(y,x,z))
model <- loess(y ~ x, data = df)
model2<-loess(z~x,data=df)
```

What I am trying to accomplish (without any luck) is to identify where the smoothed lines do 2 things:

1) I want to identify at what value(s) of x do the lines cross y=0

2) I want to identify at what value(s) of x the 2 loess lines cross each other.

I've been looking for similar problems and solutions to those problems for too long now with no success.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="loess",se=F)+
  geom_smooth(aes(y=z),method="loess",se=F)
```

Comment: Does interpolating between `model$fitted` values give you enough detail?

Comment: @Miff No I don't think so.  Ultimately I would like to report and plot (ggplot2) the x values where these lines cross 0 and where the intercept each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `predict` to get y value for any x, and then optimise to find the specific x value that solves for the y value you want.

For example, to find the zero crossing of model, we can optimise to find where the square of its fitted value is a minimum

```
zero1 <- optimize(function(x, m) predict(m, x)^2, range(x), model) 
# 
# $minimum
# [1] 67.89191
```

Note that this will only find a single local minimum.  If your model crosses zero several times, you will need to solve like this in each of the ranges where there is a zero (by changing the second argument of `optimize`, which specifies the range to search within).

Exactly the same approach can find where the models intersect. For that case you minimise the square of the difference between the two models:

```
intersection <- optimize(function(x, m1, m2) (predict(m1, x) - predict(m2, x))^2,
              range(x), model, model2)  
# $minimum
# [1] 45.65295
```

Comment: The function works as you describe, so thank you for your suggestion.  The only problem I'm having is that I need to refine this so I can pull out all values where lines of the 2 models intersect or a single line crosses zero.  I'm trying to automate this so I can produce plots with _geom.vline_ for roughly 200+ models at once. For some models the line may cross 0 a dozen times.  So to have to redefine the range a dozen times for each plot seems timely.   Any thoughts?

Comment: you can find automatically find where zero crosses by looking where the sign of the function changes between one value and the consecutive one.  Something like `which(sign(x[-1]) != sign(x[-length(x)]))` should do it